# organice-setup, version conflict issue: installs Django 1.5.12 but requires Django>=1.6

Tags: python, django

I have installed `django-organice` (version 0.2) as described in [the installation docs](http://docs.organice.io/en/latest/installation.html). All packages were installed, but when I execute:

```
$ organice-setup myexample
```

it gives the following error message

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/pathtomyvirtualenvs/bin/organice-setup", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/pathtomyvirtualenvs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2720, in <module>
    parse_requirements(_requires_), Environment()
File "/pathtomyvirtualenvs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (Django 1.5.12 (/pathtomyvirtualenvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('Django>=1.6'))
```

This is also an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Organice/django-organice/issues/7

Comment: Can someone with 1500 reputation points (or more) add the tag `django-organice` to this question, please? Thanks in advance! (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work#252945) for why I ask)

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback; which package is trying to resolve the requirement for Django 1.6 or greater?

Comment: @Peterino you already have the [open question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302688/3001761) on Meta, there's no need for a comment too (it says *"As an alternative"*!) Note that the linked post says *"if you think there is a clear need"*, which you aren't really demonstrating as yet.

Comment: Thank you, please find above my question edited with the full traceback.

Comment: @jonsharpe I think that the need you were talking about with Peterino is demonstrated by the search necessity and the added value of the django-organice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just about a clean installation, note that all releases are documented in the [CHANGELOG](http://docs.organice.io/en/latest/changelog.html); follow the *Packages* link (*Dependencies*, in future) for a documented snapshot of package versions used for a working release.

Hence, all you'd need to do is, prepare a clean virtual environment and run

```
$ pip install -r docs/requirements.txt
```

where [docs/requirements.txt](https://github.com/Organice/django-organice/blob/v0.2/docs/requirements.txt) is the requirements file of the release you want to install.

`organice-setup` should run just fine, afterwards. (The error mentioned in your question suggests there is a package in your installation that forces a newer version of Django. This can happen, because most dependencies in [setup.py](https://github.com/Organice/django-organice/blob/develop/setup.py) are not pinned, intentionally, to provide a liberal upgrade path.)